# How to know which Admin create the order in Magento 2 backend?

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, create-order, admin-order-create

I want to know who create the order.I have 5 Salesman and they have diffrence Admin ID. When customer order from other sale chanels(Facebook chat,...) and our salesman create the order on magento admin backend.

Can I know How many order that this person created for customer?

I just want to track their performance.

Please advice,
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is free Extension by kiwicommerce on https://github.com/kiwicommerce/magento2-admin-activity

Please  download and enable the same.

Here you can track all the admin activites which are happening on magento website . Also you can restrict the types of activities. There is option to enable/disable certain activies. If you want only order related activities then you can only enable order in configuration .